# Keep this context across objects

Tags: javascript, react-native, this

I am using [this](https://github.com/wookoinc/react-native-popover-tooltip) tooltip for displaying some information. When one of the options is clicked, I want to show the next tooltip. The way this transitioning has been set up by the library author is through `ref`s, and in this case, the refs work well when they are string literals. However, string literals are deprecated in React16+.

The workaround is to use `createRef` and I did that. It works for the first popup, but fails when having to transition because `this` refers to the immediate object it is used in.

Below is the code I have written. How can I change it such that `this` refers to the correct object?

```
//Constructor
constructor() {
 super();
 this.firstToolTip= React.createRef();
 this.secondToolTip = React.createRef();
}
//Body of render method
<PopoverTooltip
   ref={this.firstToolTip}
   buttonComponent={button}
   items={[
     {
       label: 'Some text for the tootip',
       onPress: () => {                     
         this.refs[this.secondToolTip].toggle();
       }
     }
   ]}
/>

<PopoverTooltip
   ref={this.secondToolTip}
   buttonComponent={button}
   items={[
     {
       label: 'Some text for the tootip',
       onPress: () => {}
     }
   ]}
/>
```

I understand that, as the other posts I have read here mention, I could bind `this` but `createRef` returns `undefined` hence that is quite impossible to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind the click function like this.

```
//Constructor
constructor() {
  super();
  this.firstToolTip= React.createRef();
  this.secondToolTip = React.createRef();
  this.clickOnFirstTooltip=this.clickOnFirstTooltip.bind(this);
}
 //Added func
 clickOnFirstTooltip(){
   // ref.current to acccesss the tooltip 
   this.secondToolTip.current.toggle();
 }
//Body of render method
<PopoverTooltip
  ref={this.firstToolTip}
  buttonComponent={button}
  items={[
    {
   label: 'Some text for the tootip',
    onPress:this.clickOnFirstTooltip
   }
  ]}
/>

<PopoverTooltip
  ref={this.secondToolTip}
  buttonComponent={button}
  items={[
    {
      label: 'Some text for the tootip',
      onPress: () => {}
     }
   ]}
  />
```

Comment: I will give this a shot later today. But I doubt if it'll work because createRef does not have a function `toggle`

Comment: The way the author transitions is thru the use of `this.refs` which I think will be undefined within a function that is at instance level

Comment: I think `this.secondToolTip.current.toggle();` is the right way

Comment: yeh I knew :D you should read more about refs in React documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: I definitely should. Thanks so much.